# What happens if I increased the number of principal components used in t-SNE?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, tsne

I see that most of the tutorials in t-SNE use mostly the top 10 PCs to run t-SNE, I tried to run top 100 PCs and top 500 PCs, the results are different but I don't really get the changes

Thank you

Comment: Since you are not telling us what the changes you saw are and why you did not really get them this is going to be quite hard to answer.

Comment: You are right, and that's the problem, I can't really understand the results!